# I copy pasted a data from elsewhere and there is some trouble with the format excel treats dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

The source excel file is in mm-dd-yyyy, and when i copy pasted the same into my excel sheet, it first chooses the data in the format mm-dd-yyyy and converts them to date and keeps the rest in text format.
[The date column is wrongly identified(mm-dd-yyyy) and split as both text and date(dd-mm-yyyy)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLlIq.png)

I tried splitting the column by delimitters, but excel stores dates differently.
I tried changing the format of the entire column to mm-dd-yyyy as well and then using that, but again the issue is excel has already processed and stored them as date or text before i can do anything.
I also created a column with the mm-dd-yyyy format and then pasted the data, but it still doesn't help.

Comment: Excel might try to use your regional settings when you input data. You can try changing the target column's format to Text. Then, you can use formulas to convert them to a date format.

Comment: =IF(ISTEXT(A1),DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2)),DATE(YEAR(A1),DAY(A1),MONTH(A1))) ?

Comment: Instead of normal paste, have u tried this?  Data > Text to Columns > (At the last window) Change the Column data type from 'General' to 'Text'